# Create autoloaded function from macro

Tags: emacs, macros, autoload

How can I get create an autoloaded function from a macro function factory?  For example, say I have a macro to create alignment functions as follows, but I want to be able to specify an option so the expanded macro has an autoload cookie.

```
(defmacro align-by (name doc regex)
  "Alignment function factory."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((fn (intern name)))
    `(defun ,fn (start end)
       ,doc
       (interactive "r")
       (align-regexp start end ,regex))))

(align-by "align-backslash"
  "Align backslashes at end of line in region."
  "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\$")
```

I know I can write this, but can I avoid needing to write this for every function?

```
;;;###autoload (autoload 'align-backslash "this-file")
```

Comment: What's the scenario where you would need to do this? I am having a hard time thinking of anything that wouldn't be solved by just autoloading the macro itself, but I am guessing this is just over my head, so I am genuinely curious.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where the macro would pick up the name of the file to be autoloaded - you do not pass a file name to the macro, currently.

Assuming that the file name comes from a file that is being visited when the macro is expanded, this will do it:

```el
(defmacro align-by (name doc regex)
  "Alignment function factory."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((fn (intern name)))
    `(progn
       ,(and (buffer-file-name)
             `(autoload ',name ,(buffer-file-name)))
       (defun ,fn (start end)
         ,doc
         (interactive "r")
         (align-regexp start end ,regex)))))
```

Testing:

```
(macroexpand '(align-by "align-backslash"
           "Align backslashes at end of line in region."
           "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\$"))
```

`C-u C-x C-e` shows that that gives this when the current buffer is not visiting a file:

```
(progn
  (autoload '"align-backslash" nil)
  (defun align-backslash
      (start end)
    "Align backslashes at end of line in region."
    (interactive "r")
    (align-regexp start end "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\$")))
```

And it gives this when the buffer is visiting file `foo.el`, where `".../foo.el"` is really the absolute file name for `foo.el`:

```
(progn
  (autoload '"align-backslash" ".../foo.el")
  (defun align-backslash
      (start end)
    "Align backslashes at end of line in region."
    (interactive "r")
    (align-regexp start end "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\$")))
```

Comment: You don't need to expand the macros: `autoload` is called along with `defun` definition when you call `(align-by "align-backslash" ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code that picks up the `;;;###autoload` cookies does expand the macros before looking at the code, so you *should* be able to just place a `;;;###autoload` cookie right before a `(align-by ...)` expression and get the right autoload placed in the `<foo>-autoloads.el` file.

The problem, tho is that your macro is probably not going to be defined at the time the autoloads are created, so the macro expansion will not actually happen.  Maybe a `M-x report-emacs-bug` is in order.

Answer (score 1):

As emacs manual [mentioned](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html)

> If you write a function definition with an unusual macro that is not one of the known and recognized function definition methods, use of an ordinary magic autoload comment would copy the whole definition into loaddefs.el. That is not desirable. You can put the desired autoload call into loaddefs.el instead by writing this:

```
;;;###autoload (autoload 'foo "myfile")
(mydefunmacro foo
  ...)
```

Your `align-by` is like `mydefunmacro` in the manual example. It is not known function definition method and it is not supported by `autoload` mechanism.

So there are three alternatives:

1. Extend the list of supported types (`defun`, `defmacro`, `cl-defun`, `defclass`,...) by your special macros. Then you can use simple `;;;###autoload` "decorator".
2. Invent your own mechanism of "myfile" parsing (without executing) and "loaddefs" populating by necessary autoload definitions.
3. Use more complicated construction (with `(autoload 'align-backslash "myfile")`) as function defintion method.

If you rewrite `align-by` like this (without `intern`):

```
(defmacro align-by-defun (name doc regex)
  "Alignment function factory."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(defun ,name (start end)
     ,doc
     (interactive "r")
     (align-regexp start end ,regex)))

;;;###autoload (autoload 'align-backslash "myfile")
(align-by-defun align-backslash
  "Align backslashes at end of line in region."
  "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\$")
```

you can see that `align-by` is just a function definition method (like `cl-defun`).

Comment: No, you can use `align-by-defun` as a function factory too. It does not matter. But do you have the full list of your functions (align-backslash, ...) in advance? Or it will be created dynamically?

Comment: Do you want all of them have `this-file` link (to `align-by` definition) in help buffer or something else?